# Does 'morality' make sense in the context of finite existence?

Tags: ethics, reference-request, social-ethics

If you believe you become completely non-existent after your death, is there any meaning or value to living morally?  If one believes in a finite existence, why is it wrong to try to acquire a lot of benefits or luxuries and live the 'high life' before one disappears forever?

Are there philosophers who have addressed this topic?

Comment: If a person has been told by 10 experts say , that the person is going to kick the bucket in approximately one month and the person believes in ONLY a finite existence what's stopping him from making his 'BUCKET-LIST' criminal ,assuming he doesn't get arrested until the end of the month?

Comment: A terminal person who will be 'functional' for a month say and who belives in a finite existance might say to himself LIVE IT UP with no restrictions ( including legal restrictions ) assuming he doesn't get arrested until the month's 'up' he might say to himself WHY NOT?

Comment: Other than empathy and/or thoughts of altruism or 'the common good' ( whatever that means) why is it 'wrong' to steal? ( just saying it is against the presently accepted laws in our society is not an answer)

Comment: How is infinite life as a motivator for morality different from an arbitrarily long, but still finite time for the punishment/consequences to come to fruition?  How is the idea of "infinite life" (as opposed to large but finite) a necessary component of this question?

Comment: Taking your comments into consideration, I see your question as  "how can you ground a moral theory in the absence of a supervening moral authority, and without basing it on finite human emotional considerations like empathy and altruism?", but this is not how I read the content of your original post.

Comment: I'm not talking about any sense of a possible infinite existence or any type of moral authority. In the movie 'Annie Hall' Woody Alan  remembering himself as a child ; he heard somewhere the Universe is going to not exist in something like a billion years and he thought what's the point of doing homework ,or anything. Of course other people with a fear of non-existence might say to themselves why be limited by 'legal' rules. Why not participate in 'venture' that will make millions with impunity ( if not caught). With a lot of money one could live like royalty before 'disappearing' forever.

Comment: Your question stipulates: under an assumption that existence is finite then ... my comment/question is: why is the finiteness so significant to this question?  If infinite existence resolves this question, then why not apply the same thought process to the finite case?  If not, why is it mentioned at all?  Note: in the infinite case you can also say "Since I have infinite existence, I can always make amends in the future for any wrongs I commit now", so it frees me in the same way that you claim finite existence does.

Comment: ONE of my points is all human beings have a fundemental fear of non-existence. Our mind-brains are constantly thinking on some 'level' even if subconsciosly . As such it is a biological system that is constantly 're-designing' itself to always be functional and it could not 'adapt' to something trying to shut it down. Of course if one is depressed or one has decided to not believe in some religion they might think they are not averse to 'dis-functioning'. So this fear of non-existence might spur one to ignore standard 'morality'.

Comment: Fundamental fear of non-existence?  That's a pretty big claim you're making.

Comment: No it's not. There are many examples in many cultures showing (obviously) the fear of the unknown. Dark stories, ghost stories, Folk tales , etc,. Why are people usually dressed in black at funerals and sad. They are sad they won't see a friend or family member for a while ; but they will see them again if they believe in an afterlife. If they think they might NEVER see them again ( because of the possibilty of non-existence ) that's extremely sad. It's for this reason I think most people ( who don't want to think about these things) repress a fear of non-existence.

Comment: The thought of possibly disappearing forever is very scary. Many well-done movies explore this theme. If we human being are cognitively constantly 'renewing' and re-combining various 'thought' structures and pocesses so as to self-sustain our 'thinking' systems ( and our ability to have 'thinking systems') this is all like we are constantly 're-designing' ourselves to NEVER 'TURN OFF'. And if we are 'self-built' to never turn off the thought of 'turning off' or 'disappearing forever' is probably contrary to our mind-brains on MANY LEVELS!

Comment: @Dave ;I wasn't talking about an infinite life span as a motivator for behavior or an arbitrarily long finite life span. I was asking about a fear of disappearing forever at any time in the future as a motivator for 'disobeying' any concepts that would limit behavior and curtail selfishness.

Comment: What I'm basically asking is could a fear of non-existence be a strong incentive to be totally self-absorbed and feel compelled to amass lots of material gain and perks before one 'disappears' forever?

Comment: @ Dave; the point I was making is whether knowledge or belief in a FINITE life was a motivator for performing risky endeavors to gain some sort of benefits if the person felt reasonably assured they will not get 'caught'. Seeing as they believe they may 'pop out' of existence at any moment in the future if they die ( even if in reasonable health) why not amass many benefits before they don't exist anymore..

Comment: I've edited and voted to reopen

Answer (score 6):

There's some non-sequiturs in your thought process.

1. Generally, whether or not people consider something to be morally right is irrelevant to reward or punishment.
2. People don't always do things they think are morally right.  Maybe because they'll be rewarded for doing what they think is wrong, or they'll be punished for doing what they think is right.

Your question implies that what a person believes is morally correct depends on whether or not they'll be rewarded or punished for it.  A better question would have been "Why would someone who believes in a finite existence do what they believe is morally correct?"

Comment: I'm not saying the person thinks the scheme is morally right or wrong. I'm asking if a person believes in a finite existence and this 'scheme' being offered is a temptation for some implied benefit when the person  might say to themselves, why not live it up by gaining more and more benefits before I don't exist anymore. What concepts or ethical principles might stop this person?

Comment: As Ransack mentions 'Why would someone who believes in a finite existence do what they believe to be what is socially considered correct?' When people say 'do the right thing' , without saying what moral or ethical principles they are referring to WHAT does that mean?

Comment: Usually, empathy (as you've mentioned in your question) with victims or the desire to follow their morals may stop them.

Comment: But if Life is finite and there are ways to increase ones benefits or perks without anything 'negative' happening to oneself ( if this is in fact what the person believes) what's stopping the person? Any appreciation of empathy for others may and has been overridden by the great force GREED. History shows this that any reasons to ignore empathy for others plus greed has inspired a lot of wrong doing. Believing in a finite life MAY be a catalyst to this..

Comment: And your point here is...?

Comment: My point is that GREED could EASILY override ANY empathy for possible victums ESPECIALLY if the person believes in a finite existence. Look at a pro's and con's type of analysis. The pro's ; the person recieving a lot of money or some such valuable items and not being found out. ALSO having a lot of money and living it up before non-existence ; going 'out' with a bang as has been said. The con's ; empathy for victums and/or getting caught and not being able to enjoy the intended perks before one doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: History shows that people do horrible things despite believing in an infinite life.

Why do you assume greed easily overrides empathy, and why do you assume that fear of the afterlife easily overrides greed?

Comment: History shows people do horrible things while believing in a finite life. Greed seems to make people who subscribe to it very self-centered. I never said the fear of a possible After-life overrides greed.

Comment: You're asking for the impossible.  If there was something that always prevents a person from doing horrible things, people wouldn't do horrible things.

Comment: That is not what I'm asking. I'm asking could a belief in a finite existence 'act' like a catalyst to some people who recieve an offer of riches with the great possibility of getting away with it.

Comment: It probably could.  Pretty much anything could be a catalyst in regards to human behavior though.

Comment: Well could a belief in a finite existence offer more of a catalyst for an offer of riches and an assurance of not getting caught than a lot of other possible 'catalysts'?

Comment: That's probably something you'd need a carefully controlled experiment to answer.

Comment: Could a fear of 'disappearing' forever motivate someone to aquire BY ANY means lots of 'luxeries'?

Comment: Wouldn't the fear of disappearing forever have the opposite effect?  Why bother doing anything when whatever you're just going to lose it all someday?

Comment: Yes it could have the depressing effect of making someone give up on life , but it could also have a rebellious effect of making someone want to do things demonstrating their wish to fight the 'condition' they believe they are in and do anything to live it up while they exist..

Answer (score 0):

> if someone is offered a role in some possibly criminal scheme and they
>   believe there is a GREAT chance of getting away with it ,what would
>   stop them?

Let me interpret this question in more general form through a first-person perspective. Somebody asks, "If I could do it, in which way I would arrange everybody's behavior and ways of thinking in order that nobody can disturb my life by its crimes or evil intentions?" This is the essence of the question, and such a quest of **guarantees** seems to be well justified. It is supposed in your text that the fear of a final judgment after death is a guarantee.

For my opinion, in a secular society, where all such believes are put aside, things can be arranged in the next way. This question should be turned to that who asked it. Is she sure that *her* behavior would be also *as good* as she asked from others? If she does not believe in the life after death, she, probably, answer like this: "Yes, I am quite sure about myself, I will not commit any crime and nether will give way to my bad intentions, all this follows from my profound moral convictions". But, in this case, why she search for more than she *can propose herself* - her profound convictions without guarantees that she really has them (there is no ways to verify her personal views)?

The schema follows from this consideration and supposes only good will. Everybody can declare her prosocial moral convictions and does not propose guarantees (it's impossible, so it's useless) that she indeed has them and in her turn does not ask others to give their guarantees. *The question simply should not be even asked*.

> if one believes in a finite existence why is it wrong to steal
>   ,relative to them ( for example)?

You have only your our convictions and nothing *more strong*, therefore, they are only your mean in this case. If one does not think that all these doings are wrong you can only try to convince him that they *are* wrong. But you can fail.

Comment: Note ; I am not talking about or thinking of this thought experiment relative to any sort of moral judgements.  I'm just referring to the behavior and attitudes that some people MAY have if they believe in a finite existence and they don't want any type of moral concepts holding them back in their pursuit of great benefits..

Answer (score 0):

Your question is if people only live for a finite time why shouldn't they do bad stuff if they think they can get away with it?

Morality is about how to make decisions. This covers everything that people usually think of as morality and more. For example, if we ask whether abortion is moral or not that's a question about how to make decisions about whether to get an abortion. People who oppose abortion would claim that a woman should always make a negative decision when considering whether to get an abortion. People who think abortion should be allowed would say that a woman should sometimes say yes when considering whether to get an abortion.

Some philosophers say morality is about emotions, dispositions and that sort of thing, e.g. - morality is about whether you should care for one child more than another or whatever. All such issues are about how you should make decisions about emotional issues and so are included in saying that morality is about how to make decisions. Some philosophers may wish to limit the set of decisions under considerations to emotions or dispositions or whatever. This rips moral problems, including moral problems about emotions, out of context and makes it more difficult to solve them. This is a substantive and bad moral theory.

The main question you ought to ask is whether the action benefits you. If the action doesn't benefit you that is a criticism of it. If there is a criticism of taking a particular action then it is a bad idea even if you don't know about the criticism. Stupidity will not stop adverse consequences of bad stuff you do, so thinking that you can do something immoral and "get away with it" will not save you.

There are some bad actions you can take that only affect you. If your respond to a fault in your computer by getting angry and hitting the computer that is bad and stupid. You took a substantial risk of harming your computer, which was a bad idea. In addition, you have wasted time by getting angry rather than trying to think about how to solve your problem. There is no such thing as getting away with doing something stupid and bad like that.

But let's suppose that you take an action that harms somebody else and you get away with it in the sense that at present the other person hasn't found out. If he does find out then he may be less willing to cooperate with you in future. You have no way of guaranteeing the other person won't find out. He might find out himself or somebody else might find out and tell him. You might inadvertently betray the secret yourself by slipping up. You have to keep track of how your deceived him and all the consequences of that or take a large risk of him finding out.

Also whether he will find out depends not just on you and him but on everybody else that either of you deals with, so there is no way you can reasonably expect to succeed. Whether other people will find out will depend on what knowledge they have now, which you largely don't know. It also depends on what knowledge they will create in the future which you can't possibly know. Other people interact with you directly and indirectly so their future knowledge is influenced by your future knowledge. You can't predict what knowledge you will have in the future because if you could predict what you will know tomorrow you would already know it.

Let's suppose that nobody finds out about the bad thing you did. Even leaving aside the cost of trying to cover up your misdeed, there is another problem. Your bad action was a result of bad ways of thinking about how to make decisions. By doing the bad thing and covering it up you have covered up your ignorance so that you haven't received feedback on how you could do better or fixed the problem yourself.

To understand more about secular morality read "The Beginning of Infinity" by David Deutsch and Ayn Rand has written a lot of relevant stuff: "The Virtue of Selfishness", "The Fountainhead", "Atlas Shrugged", "Philosophy who needs it" and "The Voice of Reason".

Comment: -1 for overly broad sentence here: "Morality is about how to make decisions." Not interested in arguing it, but there's much more to morality as normally defined than just making decisions -- at least for most contemporary ethicists.

Comment: @virmaior You're wrong, see the second paragraph of my edit.

Comment: Nope, still an overstatement. Morality includes more than just decision-making. For many contemporary accounts, it also includes attitude and disposition formation, controlling our emotions in response to external phenomenon, etc. Making the blanket claim "Morality is about how to make decisions" is still wrong. Or to put it another way, a lot of morality is not about asking whether getting an abortion is or wrong or whether killing babies with down syndrome is okay. There's plenty of other content in morality. See Nel Noddings, *Caring* or Aristotle, *Nicomachean Ethics*.

Comment: Controlling your emotions is about how to make decisions: it's about how to make decisions about emotions. Attitudes are about how you make decisions, such as the decision whether to express scorn. A sarcastic person makes the decision to express scorn more than a "nice" person, so whether you should be sarcastic is a matter of how you should make decisions. Dispositions are only morally relevant if you can control them, in which case how you deal with them is a matter of how you make certain kinds of decisions.

Comment: I didn't fail to understand you believed what you wrote when you wrote it the first time. It doesn't even matter whether I agree. What matters is that the definition you're making up is not the way the term is used in philosophy. Again, all you would need to do is make a minor change but instead you argue ...

Comment: I have made an edit, see the third paragraph of the new version. The change you ask is not minor, it is asking for an endorsement of a bad moral idea.

Comment: My question has nothing to do  with God or any deity or anything supernatural , I left those considerations out on purpose. The question's only focus is the idea of a finite existence. If there is only a finite existence there can be no punishment 'after' death. I'm just wondering how that belief in supposedly eventual non-existence effects people and their sense of how they should 'limit' their behaviour to do the 'right thing'.

Comment: Edited the first paragraph. The rest of the answer still applies.

Comment: Ayn Rand morality isn't really secular, it's more of an extreme libertarian/objectivist morality. You can be religious and still follow it.

I also have to comment, there's something amusing about the author asking what stops people from doing things that benefit themselves when there's a lack of any punishment or empathy and you come along and say that it's actually morally justified.

Comment: Rand was an atheist, so her morality is secular. 
The poster asked about criminal acts presupposing that the person benefits from committing them. I explained why this idea is misleading and you have not criticised the explanation I gave.
Rand also was not a libertarian. She regarded libertarians as irresponsible because they wanted to go into politics without doing the necessary work of changing minds first so that people would want free market reform.
Libertarians do not recommend any specific morality and many condemn Rand.

Comment: I'll concede on the secular morality point.  The poster asked why a person wouldn't self benefit when there's no reason not to do so from a self-interest point of view.  You deflected it by saying that somehow, the action wouldn't truly be self-benefiting.  This seems like a cheap way to get out of admitting that focusing on self-benefit might make you do horrible things.  And regardless of what Rand thinks of libertarians, a large part of her philosophy falls under libertarianism.  Enough to be considered a libertarian, albeit an extreme and niche form of libertarianism.

Comment: Do you have an example of an action you think would benefit yourself that I didn't cover, or do you have a specific criticism of the argument I gave?

Comment: The point of the question was "What should I do if an action harms someone else but benefits myself?"  You failed to answer the question, instead arguing that somehow the action will carry some kind of hidden cost that makes it unbeneficial to you overall.  Rather than following through with the implications of the selfishness philosophy, you deny that situations where the best action for self benefit at the cost of unjustly hurting others even exist.

Comment: I argue that there are no situations in which others are unjustly hurt and you benefit. You describe my strategy as pointing out there is a hidden cost to unjustly hurting other people. This is not accurate. The costs aren't hidden, it's just that some people don't know about them. You haven't argued that the problems I point out don't happen. So there are no substantive criticisms of my position in your comment.

Comment: Your philosophy hinges on the idea that there are no situations where the best action; the action that leads to the most benefit for yourself, can unjustly hurt others.  Most people would consider that an absurd assertion.  Each time you point out a problem you use words such as "might" or "if".  When you say a problem might happen, it implies that there's also the possibility that the problem might not happen.  I don't know why you always ignore the latter possibility. Lets suppose there's an action that greatly benefits yourself at no cost but greatly hurts others unjustly.  What do you do?

Comment: My use of the words "might" or "if" doesn't indicate that the cost is entirely hypothetical. You have to take action to avoid the "might" or "if" scenarios and those actions have a cost independent of whether the "might" or "if" occurs. Also, the cost pointed out in the second last paragraph does not involve "might" or "if" at all.

Comment: And you assume that if there's an action that unjustly hurts others, the cost/risk is always going to overcome the benefits, because...?

Comment: It's not a matter of benefit outweighing cost. If there is a criticism of doing something you shouldn't do it. I gave a load of criticisms of ripping people off, so you shouldn't do it.

Comment: Why wouldn't you do something just because someone criticizes you for it?  I thought the main concern was whether or not the action benefits you.

Comment: The problem is not that somebody else might criticise you for it, the problem that there is a criticism. For example, if you get somebody to give you money for your start up by lying to them, if you had told them the truth they might have given you a reason to ditch the business and do something else, or they might have a solution to some problem with your start up. If you had come up with the idea by yourself it would still be a reason to do something different from what you were planning before.

Comment: Why would you do something different if what you currently have is what would maximize your self-benefit?

Comment: You seem to be thinking in terms of a fixed menu of options from which you pick the best. But there isn't a fixed menu. You can solve new problems and get something better than any of the options you had before you solved the problems.

Comment: That's incredibly optimistic and unrealistic.  If you're always going to convince yourself that it's in your rational self-interest to not be evil, why even bother with the selfishness philosophy?

Comment: I am an optimist in the sense of thinking problems can be solved, that doesn't imply people will solve them. See Chapter 9 of "Beginning of Infinity". Morality is about how to make decisions. You should aim for unbounded improvement rather than just not being evil. Rational selfishness helps with that: if you only do stuff you think is right you have a class of potential criticisms of your position that can help improve it. If other people do that too, then still more criticism is available to help improve your options.

Comment: That idea isn't rooted in reality.  Not all problems can be solved.  And rational selfishness doesn't necessarily lead to improvement, at least not for society as a whole.

Comment: All problems can be solved. For an explanation see "Beginning of Infinity" chapter 9. As for rational selfishness not leading to improvement for society as a whole, there are problems with this argument. What people commonly call society is just people and a bunch of institutions (knowledge about how to do stuff like the rules of the House of Commons or the protocols for transferring information on the internet). Rational selfishness would improve both individuals and knowledge so it would improve society.

Comment: ...Your entire philosophy is based on extremely shaky assertions.  "All problems can be solved" is an absurd position.  "Rational selfishness would improve society" is an unsupported assertion.  Improving one person while hurting many others in the process is a net loss for society.  Rational selfishness doesn't even necessarily lead to knowledge.  Rand wasn't an expert on how science and progress is usually made.

Comment: Please take lengthy discussions to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/)! :)

Answer (score 0):

Beyond what Ransack indicated, there's another flaw in your presentation:  you assert that people who have enough empathy for the victims will be deterred by that, but then dismiss this case by saying that there are many criminals who are not empathetic.  But at least a plurality of those non-empathetic criminals are not deterred by the prospect of supernatural punishment, e.g. declared Christians who have stolen from someone else.

Thus, in your own presentation you have indicated that (a) sufficient empathy for the victims will prevent someone from committing a crime, even in the absence of other punishments, (b) even supernatural promises of punishment is insufficient to deter all people from committing crimes.  So my take away from your presentation is that ethics is hard.

To more directly answer your question: I'm not convinced that secular morality is in ever in conflict with *enlightened* self interest.  The enlightened aspect include features like, considering the long term consequences, considering what would happen if your actions were a general rule (akin to rule utilitarianism), considerations of others (e.g. [the veil of ignorance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veil_of_ignorance)) etc.

Comment: No I implied a person's sense of empathy MAY stop them from doing some possible crime.

Comment: By construction, _enough_ empathy (what I wrote in the first paragraph) or _sufficient_ empathy, as in the second, will prevent the person from committing the crime.  All that matters for my argument is that there are some people in some moral situations for whom empathetic considerations are sufficient to guide them towards the moral choice even in the absence of other reward/punishment factors.  I read your question to indicate that you acknowledge that such situations exist.

Comment: Yes , empathy victums of a con-game or a white collar crime or any other crime COULD be enough to stop a person from participating BUT there is also the LOVE of money and all the perks it can supply if the scheme is not found out. How do con-artists get a 'reasonable' and up-to-now law abiding citizen to participate in a scheme? Probably the promise of money and 'perks' and the assurance it's not a crime or no one will get hurt , or it's a brilliant plan that will never be discovered. If a person believes in a finite existence and that they won't be found out in this present life, WHY NOT?

Comment: I am not ever indirectly referring to ANY possibility of supernatural punishments , my intent is regarding the attitudes of people who believe in a finite life in this life only and how it MIGHT affect their ambitions for 'benefits'.. Of course people with empathy may limit their behavior and they may not but the point is someone striving for benefits ,without getting caught if illicit, may ignore any possible behavior  limiting concepts to 'enjoy'  themselves before they ultimately disappear.... forever..